# How to see if an image is contained in another image image and get an output of 1 if there is or 0 if there isn't?

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

I have a script that takes a screenshot of the screen and I want to see if a smaller image is within it. I'm currently using pyAutoGui to take the screenshot. I know that I can use open-cv but I don't know how to turn it into a boolean value, like when the smaller image is detected to give a 1 or like True and when it's not to give a 0 or False. Thank You!

Comment: Please post a link to an example image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cv2.matchTemplate` method:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread("image1.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("image2.png")

img1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img1_gray, img2_gray, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
if np.any(res > 0.9):
    print("Image2 is in Image1.")
```

were the `0.9` represents the amount of confidence required in order for the image to be classified as inside the other image. For more accuracy, you can do:

```
if np.any(res > 0.99):
```